# How add own images for react native emulator/ImagePicker

Tags: react-native

When open the gallery I see only 6 default images for emulator, how add custom?

```
ImagePicker.openPicker({
  multiple: true,
  mediaType: 'photo',
  forceJpg: true,
}).then((images) =>
  setImagesMeta((prevState) => {
    return [...images, ...prevState]
  })
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. On iOS Simulator you can add images via drag & drop
2. For android you can use adb push